# Pass a big object to an action on a controller from a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass a big object to a controller's action from a view. Like so:

**View**

```
<div>@Html.ActionLink("Send us an email", "Index", 
"Email", new { o = @Model.Exception }, null)</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public class EmailController : Controller
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index(object o)
        {
            new BaseServices.Emailer().SendEmail(o);

            return View();
        }

    }
```

The thing is: the object being passed is so large that I guess that MVC is unable to make an argument out of that and add it to the route table/dictionary. So, my email controller's Index action is never called. The code bombs off somewhere in between.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do this. ASP.NET MVC is not some *magic*. It relies on standard HTTP and HTML. And as you know in HTTP when you are using a GET request, there's no notion of *.NET objects*. You cannot ask *how to pass an object* in a web application because this is not defined.

There's a notion of query string parameters. So that's what you can pass => simple query string parameters:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Send us an email", 
    "Index", 
    "Email", 
    new { id = Model.Exception.Id, text = Model.Exception.Text }, 
    null
)
```

Where the magic comes is that ASP.NET MVC will now use the 2 simple query string parameters (id and text) to map them to the corresponding properties of your view model inside the controller action.

But of course for this to work ASP.NET MVC needs to know the type of the model. You cannot just use `object` because this type doesn't have `id` nor `text` properties.

So:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel o)
```

Now but what about sending complex types? Well, the question that you have to ask to yourself is why on the first place this type was passed to the view? Was it because tfhe user was supposed to edit some of its properties? Is so then you should use an HTML form containing input fields allowing the user to edit them.

But since you have stuck this object into an anchor then what's the point? The server could fetch this object from wherever it fetched it in the first place. So all you need is to pass a simple id to the server:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Send us an email", 
    "Index", 
    "Email", 
    new { id = Model.Exception.Id }, 
    null
)
```

and have the controller action take this id as parameter:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
```

Alright now you know the id => therefore you could retrieve the corresponding entity from wherever this entity is persisted.

Now some people might suggest you storing the object into the session before rendering the view and then retrieving this object from the session. Personally I am not a big fan of the session as it introduces state into the application. This means that you can never invoke the second action without first invoking the first action. This also means that you cannot bookmark the second action into the browser favorites. This also means that if you are running your application in a web-farm you can no longer store the session in-memory => you will have to use an out-of-process storage for this session. Sessions are way too much of a hassle.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by my question. The query string parameter is too large. I need a way to pass an object to the action on the controller. My question is: how do I do that?

Comment: That's not possible, sorry. As I said that's not how the HTTP protocol works. There's no notion of `object` in the HTTP protocol. So asking `how to pass an object using the HTTP protocol` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really pass it in the view.

Instead, consider storing the exception in TempData in the controller that renders the view....

```
public ActionResult DisplayErrorAndOptionToEmailIt()
{

    TempData["LastError"] = m.Exception;
    return View();
}
```

and then when the request comes in retrieve it from temp data and email it

```
public ActionResult SendTheEmail()
{
    var e = TempData["LastError"] as Exception;
    if (e != null)
    {
        EmailHelper.SendExceptionEmail(e);
    }
    return View();
}
```

On a side note, it's not the best practice to store complete objects.  If possible, store only what you need:

```
public ActionResult DisplayErrorAndOptionToEmailIt()
{

    TempData["LastError"] = m.Exception.Message;
    return View();
}
```